# SQL percentages between tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL question that I've been struggling to figure out.

Assume I have these two tables. For the first table, I have users who are assigned an A/B test and a version A or B. For the second table, I have events stored for each user who interacts with a page. (Every user with a 'clicked' event initially has a 'loaded' event).

Table: **dbo.tests**

```
|user | test_name| version |
+-----+----------+---------+
| 1   | "foo"    | "A"     |
| 1   | "bar"    | "B"     |
| 2   | "foo"    | "A"     |
| 3   | "bar"    | "B"     |
```

Table: **dbo.events**

```
|user | event           | event_date |
+-----+-----------------+------------+
| 1   | "loaded"        | 2019-01-01 |
| 1   | "clicked"       | 2019-01-02 |
| 2   | "loaded"        | 2019-05-29 |
| 3   | "loaded"        | 2019-06-01 |
```

I want to produce a table that calculates cardinal sums for each combination of event and test as a percentage. My instinct is to use a correlated subquery and somehow combine it with a left join, but I can't figure out the right syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is a `join` with conditional aggregation:

```
select u.test_name,
       (sum(case when e.event = 'clicked' then 1.0 else 0 end) /
        sum(case when e.event = 'loaded' then 1 end)
       )
from users u left join
     events e
     on u.user = e.user
group by u.test_name;
```

Note:  This doesn't check for the "loaded" event paired with the "clicked" one, because you say it is always there.

If users could have duplicate events, then use `count(distinct)`:

```
select u.test_name,
       (count(distinct case when e.event = 'clicked' then u.user end) * 1.0 /
        count(distinct case when e.event = 'loaded' then 1 end u.user end)
       )
from users u left join
     events e
     on u.user = e.user
group by u.test_name;
```

Comment: This was super helpful, definitely put me in the right direction.